# C Program crashing upon declaration of a variable

Tags: c, variables, memory, crash, declaration

I have been randomly plagued by this problem and I cant seem to figure out what is causing it.

I have a function that declares a large number of variables,pointers, and arrays.  However at a certain point my program seems to crash if I declare a new variable.  Even when it does crash it does not seem to be consistent.  If the code below of my function, if I declare the variable b as an int it will crash the program, but if I declare it as int b[10] it will not.

My apologies for the large amount of code, but I wanted to provide the whole function in case I am missing something.  the variable b I am referring to is near the top.

I suspect it is some sort of memory issue, but what I have seen does not seem real consistent.

```
static should_inline void decode_image_internal(PictureDecoderData* pdd, FILE* outfile)
{
  unsigned int mb_row;
  unsigned int mb_col;
  unsigned int mb_idx;
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int j;
  unsigned int b[10];
  unsigned char topy[30720];
  unsigned char topcb[7680];
  unsigned char topcr[7680];

  Picture* pic = pdd->pic;
  unsigned int bottom_field_flag = pdd->prev_sh->bottom_field_flag; // TODO: remove the     use of prev_sh since it really depends on the pdd decoding context.
  slice_header_t* slice0 = pic->field_sh[bottom_field_flag][0]; // get a slice header.   It is used for variables that are the same for the whole picture
  seq_parameter_set_rbsp_t* sps = slice0->sps;
  pic_parameter_set_rbsp_t* pps = slice0->pps;
  int PicWidthInMbs = sps->PicWidthInMbs;
  unsigned int PicWidthY = PicWidthInMbs * 16;
  unsigned int PicHeightInMbs = slice0->PicHeightInMbs;
  unsigned int PicSizeInMbs = PicWidthInMbs*PicHeightInMbs;
  int CurrMbAddr;
  MbAttrib* mb_attr = pic->field_data[bottom_field_flag].mb_attr;
  MbAttrib* curr_mb_attr;
  unsigned int mbc_width = MbWidthC[1];
  unsigned int mbc_height = MbHeightC[1];
//  unsigned int mbc_size = mbc_width*mbc_height;
  unsigned int PicWidthC = PicWidthInMbs * mbc_width;
  int clipY = (1<<sps->BitDepthY)-1;
  int meanY = 1<<(sps->BitDepthY-1);
  int clipC = (1<<sps->BitDepthC)-1;
  int meanC = 1<<(sps->BitDepthC-1);
  int mb_data_size = (256+2*MbSizeC[1]);
  int16_t* mb_data = pic->field_data[bottom_field_flag].data;
  int16_t* curr_mb_data;
  unsigned int field_pic_flag = slice0->field_pic_flag;
  unsigned int strideY = PicWidthY << field_pic_flag;
  unsigned int strideC = PicWidthC << field_pic_flag;
  slice_header_t* sh;
  unsigned int constrained_intra_pred_flag = pps->constrained_intra_pred_flag;

  pixel_t* Y;
  pixel_t* C[2];
  pixel_t* y;
  pixel_t* c[2];

  Y = (pixel_t*)((uint32_t)pic->Y + (bottom_field_flag!=0)*PicWidthY);
  C[0] = (pixel_t*)((uint32_t)pic->C[0]+ (bottom_field_flag!=0)*PicWidthC);
  C[1] = (pixel_t*)((uint32_t)pic->C[1]+ (bottom_field_flag!=0)*PicWidthC);


  for (j = 0; j<=pic->slice_num[bottom_field_flag]; j++)
  {
    sh = pic->field_sh[bottom_field_flag][j];
    CurrMbAddr = sh->first_mb_in_slice;

    //for (i = 0; i<sh->mb_nb; i++)
     for (i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
      pixel_t ysamp[256], cbsamp[8*8], crsamp[8*8];
      mb_row = (CurrMbAddr) / PicWidthInMbs;
      mb_col = (CurrMbAddr) % PicWidthInMbs;
      mb_idx = (CurrMbAddr);
      curr_mb_attr = &mb_attr[mb_idx];
      curr_mb_data = mb_data + mb_idx * mb_data_size;
     // printf(" %d %d \n ",strideY, mb_row);
      y = Y + mb_col*16 + mb_row*strideY*16;
      c[0] = C[0] + mb_col*mbc_width + mb_row*strideC*mbc_height;
      c[1] = C[1] + mb_col*mbc_width + mb_row*strideC*mbc_height;


        {
          MB_TYPE mb_type = curr_mb_attr->mb_type;
          unsigned int mb_field_decoding_flag = curr_mb_attr->mb_field_decoding_flag;
          pixel_t* mb_C_samples[2];

          mb_C_samples[0] = c[0];
          mb_C_samples[1] = c[1];


          //if (mb_type <= SI) // Intra mb
            decode_intra_mb(curr_mb_attr, mb_type, curr_mb_data, 1920, 960, y, mb_C_samples[0], mb_C_samples[1],
            ysamp, cbsamp, crsamp,
            mbc_height, mbc_width, clipY, clipC, meanY, meanC, mb_field_decoding_flag, mb_row&1, PicWidthInMbs, 0,
            constrained_intra_pred_flag);

            rgbconvert(ysamp, cbsamp, crsamp, outfile);


        }

      CurrMbAddr = NextMbAddress(sh->MbToSliceGroupMap, CurrMbAddr, PicSizeInMbs, pps->num_slice_groups_minus1);
    }

  }


  // Release the ref picture it was using
  release_picture_refpics(pic, bottom_field_flag); // it is OK even when the pic is a frame because both field points to the same lists

  filter_image(pic, bottom_field_flag);

  // Output the picture !
  add_image_to_dpb(pic);
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Edit*  Thanks for the replies guys!  Turns out corruption of the stack was the correct answer.  I am on my way to getting it fixed.

Comment: This symptom pretty much always means that your code is overwriting the stack, in some way. You need to either run it in a debugger (or, better, a memory violation detector such as Valgrind) or go through and analyze each write it does to figure out where it's failing.

Comment: Not an answer to the problem, but definitely good guidance, use Valgrind: http://www.valgrind.org/ Example usage here: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/purify.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*if I declare the variable b as an int it will crash the program, but if I declare it as int b[10] it will not.*

The obvious reason is that with the latter you will reserve 10 times as much memory.  However, you don't appear to be using `b` anywhere, so almost certainly you are overrunning memory somewhere else.  The difference is that reserving extra memory stops the bug overwriting something critical (same as when a program only works under Debug).

Trouble is that this is only a portion of the program, the actual error could be elsewhere since you are calling other functions and using data passed in as arguments.

`bottom_field_flag` is an obvious value to check.

You do not mention what type of crash you get.  This is critical to taking the resolution further.  For example, if you get a stack overflow, and you are on Windows, then you need to check the stack size setting in your compiler (I think /F and a linker option in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2):

Allocate too much large arrays on stack is a *BAD* idea. Stack is not meant for this, and you will easily run out of stack memory. Even worse, it's hard to control and catch such an issue.

Instead you have to allocate large amounts of memory on *heap*. There is much more memory there (but not infinite, of course!)

In short, replacing

```
unsigned char topy[30720];
```

with

```
unsigned char* topy = (char*)malloc(30720);
```

must be much better and probably will eliminate your issue. Just don't forget to free allocated memory (`free(topy)`) when it is no longer needed.

**UPD**: of course, theese are general reasoning, and they *do not* apply to special cases (i.e. embedded systems, etc).

Comment: **50kb** on the stack which defaults to 1MB is fine for a non-recursive function. In fact it is good to not have heap-dependency if you dont need it.

Comment: It turns out I was corrupting the stack in decode_intra_mb() function.

I have my arrays declared like that because I am developing this for an embedded platform where I cannot use malloc and the memory will be statically assigned.  So I am just planning ahead I guess

Comment: @eznme I see, and mainly my answer was based on an assumption that the OP is using this techique widely, and all functions *together* finally have a critical mass. I was wrong, though, sorry. Of course if one knows what he does, there is nothing wrong in such stack arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating-system? If this is on **Windows** then this is most likely caused by the chkstk-routine your compiler inserts without asking when it sees a function with >4k locals. And if you used **-nostdlib** then this fails.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind (as proposed by @nevelis) is a very good idea to solve such issues.

Another option is executing the application with debugger (**gdb**), wait for the crash and look at the back trace.

In gdb the commands are:

```
run
```

and after the crash:

```
bt
```

I think you should also reduce the stack size (automatic variables). 44K on stack does not seem like a good idea.